# Xtext zero ('0') not matching INT

Tags: dsl, xtext

I've written an Xtext grammar that describes a list of coordinates:

```
Model:
    coordinates+=Coordinates*
;
Coordinates:
    '(' x=INT ',' y=INT ')'
;
```

However, when using the parsingTest automatically created with a new Xtext project and printing `println(EmfFormatter.objToStr(result))` for this program:

```
(2,1)
(2,0)
(0,1)
(0,0)
(1,1)
```

I get the following representation of the AST:

```
Model {
    cref Coordinates coordinates [
        0: Coordinates {
            attr EInt x '2'
            attr EInt y '1'
        }
        1: Coordinates {
            attr EInt x '2'
        }
        2: Coordinates {
            attr EInt y '1'
        }
        3: Coordinates {
        }
        4: Coordinates {
            attr EInt x '1'
            attr EInt y '1'
        }
    ]
}
```

What I think is happening is that '0' does not match INT for some reason.  I could create a new datatype, but seems quite ugly not to use the provided INT. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the other terminals/keywords in your grammar and/or a minimal but complete grammar. are you sure it does not match? what is the parse errors you get? are you sure what EmfFormatter prints values equal to default values?

Comment: The grammar I included is complete and can be tested with the example program above (the list of coordinates). Indeed the problem was with EmfFormatter, it does not print the value if it is equal to the default. I manually checked the values of the coordinates and it is 0 when it should, even though it doesn't show when printed. If you make your comment a reply, I'll be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy. There is no problem. The EmfFormatter simply does not print values equal to default values